# silent uninstaller

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

I have taken over work on a vs desktop application...

The setup program has an un-installer which is simply the uninstall.bat file

```
msiexe /x {PRODCODE}
```

when this runs one of the message windows is a 'are you sure you want to uninstall' and a DOS window opens with the command in the batch file showing.

Ideally I'd like to be rid of both of these - the dos window would be great, can live with the message box...

any tips on achieving this would be most welcome.

thanks you lovely people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msiexec /qb! /x {PRODCODE} should disable the confirmation message, also displaying the operation progress window. You could try the other options: /q, /qn, etc.

Comment: thanks buddy - I ended up using /qn - still get the command line window opening up showing the command in the bat file but I can live with that)